# unable to install pip on python 2.6.6 - lack of dependencies

Tags: pip, python-2.6

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and using python 2.6.6 that I installed from tgz package from here https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-266/ using this instruction: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file. I'm trying to install pip using this instruction https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

but when I run

> python get-pip.py

I got errors about dependencies:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get-pip.py", line 28, in
>   
>       import tempfile   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 34, in 
>       from random import Random as _Random   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/random.py", line 47, in 
>       from os import urandom as _urandom ImportError: cannot import name urandom

First it was cannot import name `zlib`. I installed `zlib` and now I got about urandom so I guess there might be more that I don't have installed. What's the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Function `urandom` is imported to module `os` from module `posix` written in C. First try to verify it's there: `python2.6 -c "from posix import urandom"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try sudo. If that doesn't work, try stating the python version.

```
$ sudo python2.6 get-pip.py
```

Comment: Why do you think root privilege would help? Is the error about permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to install via OS package:

`apt install python python-pip python-setuptools`

Comment: `apt install python` wouldn't install Python 2.6. The OP has compiled Python 2.6 herself.